# Passing data-* to bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, bootstrap-modal

I have seen the many search results for passing data to a modal, all with possible working but different solutions. I have a MySql DB, with a very simple single table. I am using PHP echo to echo the data to a HTML table. The final `<td>` is a bootstrap button to trigger a modal. I am unable to get the included code to work to show the row data in the modal.

There are a lot of comments in here as I am learning.

```
<?php
/* mysql connect info */
$mysqlhost = '';
$mysqlusername = '';
$mysqlpassword = '';
$mysqldb = '';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Website | Login</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<?php    
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysqlhost, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword,  $mysqldb);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM leads";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

// Associative array
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <h1>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true"> 
    </a>
  </h1>
</div> 
</div>
</nav>

<header id="header">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</header>

<!-- Beginning of Sections -->
<section id="main">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="container">

<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <!--<th>Lead Number</th>-->
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Moving Date</th>
    <th>eMail</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>From</th>
    <th>To</th>
    <th>Moving Size</th>
    <!--<th>IP Address</th>-->
    <!--<th>Source</th>-->
    <th>Submission Time</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>


<?php
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
 echo "<tr>";
/*echo "<td>" . $row["lead_id"] ."<td>";*/
 echo "<td>" . $row["customer_first_name"] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["customer_last_name"] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["moving_date"] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["customer_email"] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["customer_phone"] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["customer_from_zip"] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["customer_to_zip"] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["customer_moving_size"] ."</td>";
/*echo "<td>" . $row["customer_ip_address"] ."<td>";*/
/*echo "<td>" . $row["lead_handle"] ."</td>";*/
echo "<td>" . $row["sent_date"] ."</td>";
echo "<td> <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\    data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\" data-id=\"". $row["lead_id"]."\">Edit</button></td>";
echo "</tr>";   }
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";

?>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


</section>



<footer id="footerindex">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">      
  </div>
</div>
</footer>

</div>









 <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<!-- this is google jquery library-->

<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/my.js"></script> 
<!-- This is the functionality of the login screen -->

<!-- at one point the drop down was not working because we did not include the bootstrap.js which much come after the initial include to the jquery library-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.js">

$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
  var id = button.data('id') 
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('Lead Number ' + id)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})

</script>



<!-- MODAL BEGIND -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body1">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

</body>
</html>
```

Also can you let me know if you can add jQuery scripts inside the html and do they override the other jquery for that activates the modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is good to keep code more cleaner by using indent well.
2. `<script ~~>` is also a tag like div , p , h1 but it has display : none. So of course you can add `<script>` tag in html file. It's OK.
3. When Browser meet that `<script src = "jquery.js">`, the browser gets the jquery.js code from server ( in this case , your server ). So, You can't override other js code. It's just twice the work for the browser, and the jquery code is read twice.
4. I can't understand what are you doing, specifically the `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.js">` code. You already included jquery-3.1.1.js above! Why are you doing that?
5. Anyway, browser can not find #myModal in timing(or time?) that read the code $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) { ~~ . So the code should be ***under*** the model div.

Be Happy Coding ^^.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the response and help. You did solve my problem. The problem I had with the indentations is when I copy/pasted the code-- I had to put 4 spaces on each line to make it appear as code for the question. Maybe there is a better way to do this? Thanks again.

Comment: It is case by case what indents you use. But , usually 4indents or 2indents! .